# Embed user timeline - Twitterkit/Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, twitter, twitter-fabric

Could someone please explain how to use TwitterKit start to finish to setup and iOS/Swift view controller to display a single user's timeline.  The documentation on Fabric is poor and doesn't explain all app delegate/view controllers necessary.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for a tutorial...

Answer (score 2):

Here's a little GIF of the main steps required to show a timeline in your app.

[image: Demo]

Answer (score 0):

Add Fabric to your project https://docs.fabric.io/apple/fabric/overview.html its very easy.

```
import TwitterKit
```

**Swift 3**

```
    // Create an API client and data source to fetch Tweets for the timeline
    let client = TWTRAPIClient()
    //TODO: Replace with your collection id or a different data source
    let dataSource = TWTRCollectionTimelineDataSource(collectionID: "539487832448843776", apiClient: client)
    // Create the timeline view controller
    let timelineViewControlller = TWTRTimelineViewController(dataSource: dataSource)
    // Create done button to dismiss the view controller
    let button = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: self, action: #selector(dismissTimeline))
    timelineViewControlller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = button
    // Create a navigation controller to hold the
    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: timelineViewControlller)
    showDetailViewController(navigationController, sender: self)
```